# Laravel select element in Form not inserting value

Tags: laravel

I modified the register controller AND the user table to have a role attribute as a string:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('role')->nullable()->index();
    });
```

and i have created an enums.php in config folder like this:

```
return [
'role_types' => [
    'ADMIN' => "Admin",
    'TEACHER' => "Teacher",
    'STUDENT' => "Student",
]];
```

on the register user view (which is scaffold by default with bootstrap)
i made select box to accommodate the selection:

```
<select class="form-control" id="role" name='role'>
           @foreach (Config::get('enums.role_types') as $role)
                    <option value="{{ $role }}">{{$role}}</option>
           @endforeach
</select>
```

But up on registering the user, the value is NULL.. what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Check the request on form submission, `dd(request());`

Comment: the dd(request()); on the create method on the register controller returns the following:
request: ParameterBag {#41 ▼
    #parameters: array:6 [▼
      "_token" => "OwStAMhDtUAOf5JS76mry2lVVA7Q0G5IE6et20EU"
      "name" => "teacher"
      "email" => "123@qwe.com"
      "role" => "Teacher"
      "password" => "123456"
      "password_confirmation" => "123456"
    ]

Comment: There is `"role" => "Teacher"`. How did you save into database?

Comment: protected function create(array $data)
    {
        dd(request());
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'role' => $data['role'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    } 
the controller 
and the table attribute as set from above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `Model::create()` you have to set your model's fillable array:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'name',
    'role',
    ...
];
```

Laravel does not let you mass assign a row using data it cannot trust. Check the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Comment: thank you so much.. i have totally forgotten about fillable array in model.. That worked.